# How to read QLineEdit and QCheckBox value when clicked on a PushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Am trying to use below code but when executed it say "Python has stopped working" and it restarts the shell. Basically am trying to read the text from QLineEdit (user input) value when the button is clicked, but it fails.

```
class Display(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        search_dir_label = QLabel('Directory to Search')
        search_dir_te = QLineEdit()
        search_dir_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        search_dir_layout.addWidget(search_dir_label)
        search_dir_layout.addWidget(search_dir_te)
        vert_layout1.addLayout(search_dir_layout)

        search_button = QPushButton('Search')
        search_button.clicked.connect(self.sendval)   
        cancel_button = QPushButton('Cancel')
        search_cancel_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        search_cancel_layout.addWidget(search_button)
        search_cancel_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)
        search_cancel_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        vert_layout1.addLayout(search_cancel_layout)

    def sendval(self):
        print(self.search_dir_te.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `search_dir_te` to `self.search_dir_te` in `initUI()` so it can be accessed in other functions. Also, add the parenthesis to call the method `text()` in `sendval()`

```
def initUI(self):
    search_dir_label = QLabel('Directory to Search')
    self.search_dir_te = QLineEdit()
    search_dir_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
    search_dir_layout.addWidget(search_dir_label)
    search_dir_layout.addWidget(self.search_dir_te)
    vert_layout1.addLayout(search_dir_layout)

    search_button = QPushButton('Search')
    search_button.clicked.connect(self.sendval)   
    cancel_button = QPushButton('Cancel')
    search_cancel_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
    search_cancel_layout.addWidget(search_button)
    search_cancel_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)
    search_cancel_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    vert_layout1.addLayout(search_cancel_layout)

def sendval(self):
    print(self.search_dir_te.text())
```